# Python urlparse.parse_qs unicode url

Tags: python, django, urlencode, urlparse

`urlparse.parse_qs` is usefull for parsing url parameters, and it works fine with simple ASCII url, represented by `str`. So i can parse a query and then construct the same path using `urllib.urlencode` from parsed data:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> import urllib
>>>
>>> path = '/?key=value' #path is str
>>> query = urlparse.urlparse(path).query
>>> query
'key=value'
>>> query_dict = urlparse.parse_qs(query)
>>> query_dict
{'key': ['value']}
>>> '/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_dict, doseq=True)
'/?key=value' # <-- path is the same here
```

It also works fine, when url contains percent encoded non-ASCII param:

```
>>> value = urllib.quote(u'значение'.encode('utf8'))
>>> value
'%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5'
>>> path = '/?key=%s' % value
>>> path
'/?key=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5'
>>> query = urlparse.urlparse(path).query
>>> query
'key=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5'
>>> query_dict = urlparse.parse_qs(query)
>>> query_dict
{'key': ['\xd0\xb7\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5']}

>>> '/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_dict, doseq=True)
'/?key=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5'  # <-- path is the same here
```

But, when using django, i get the url using `request.get_full_path()`, and it returns path as `unicode` string:

```
>>> path = request.get_full_path()
>>> path
u'/?key=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5' # path is unicode
```

Look what will happen now:

```
>>> query = urlparse.urlparse(path).query
>>> query
u'key=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5'
>>> query_dict = urlparse.parse_qs(query)
>>> query_dict
{u'key': [u'\xd0\xb7\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5']}
>>>
```

`query_dict` contains unicode string, that contains bytes! Not unicode points!
And of course i've got a UnicodeEncodeError, when trying to urlencode that string:

```
>>> urllib.urlencode(query_dict, doseq=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib.py", line 1337, in urlencode
    l.append(k + '=' + quote_plus(str(elt)))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Currently i have a solution:

```
# just convert path, returned by request.get_full_path(), to `str` explicitly:
path = str(request.get_full_path())
```

So the questions are:

- why parse_qs return so strange string (unicode, that contains bytes)?
- is it safe to convert url to str?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Encode back to bytes *before* passing it to `.parse_qs()`, using ASCII:

```
query_dict = urlparse.parse_qs(query.encode('ASCII'))
```

This does the same thing as `str()` but with an explicit encoding. Yes, this is safe, the URL encoding uses ASCII codepoints *only*.

`parse_qs` was handed a Unicode value, so it returned you a unicode value too; it is not it's job to decode bytes.